# How do I prevent duplicate headers when dealing with threads in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, cgi, header

I've written a PHP script that has to fork and do some processing in parallel, and then the main page returns data after processing. I'm currently using the pcntl functions to do this. I need to run anywhere between 2 and 10 threads to work in parallel, and I have to wait until I get a result from all of the threads before the script outputs to the browser.

Unfortunately, I find that I have multiple "Content-Type" headers appearing in the output:

```
Content-Type: text/plain

Content-Type: text/plain

Content-Type: text/plain
[... actual content ...]
```

It seems to be one header per thread spawned. I've tried to close `STDOUT` via `fclose(STDOUT)` before processing, and I've tried surrounding everything by output buffering to no avail. I haven't yet found anyone else with this problem, so either nobody is trying to do it or I'm doing something that's off the beaten track.

I'm really looking for either ways to stop this happening, or suggestions on alternative ways to get this done.

The server is set up to use PHP as CGI under mod_suPHP, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I can't tell you anything useful without a proper code sample

Comment: If a header key exists it will be overwritten, in my opinion.

Comment: I believe forking from inside of apache is a no-no.  Spawn a new process via exec, and have *that* one fork.

Comment: Sample output (with two threads): http://uri.me.uk/l

Relevant code: http://pastebin.com/f25f198ae

Comment: @Frank: PHP is running via CGI, so as I understand things I'm not in Apache, just called from it.

Comment: The "Content-Type" headers get probably sent from the exiting childs.

Unfortunately, your code does not work as-is, but I think you need to prevent the childs from exiting (too early).

Comment: @powtac: It won't, as these are separate processes.

@blueyed: That's my guess, yes. I just pasted the relevant parts... the entire codebase is fairly involved. I can't prevent the children from exiting, as that's how they signal completion. I think I'm going to have to go for Frank's solution... spawn an extra process that does the forking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try session variables?
You could set a session variable in each of the scripts when they are complete/successful and then check/wait to see if they are complete/successful in your main process.